# ¿Cómo evitar que se subraye el espacio entre icono y texto?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, css3

Tengo un enlace que consiste en un icono (un *glyphicon* de Bootstrap) y un texto. En estado normal el enlace está sin subrayar y cuando se pasa el ratón por encima se subraya.

El problema es que, cuando paso el ratón por encima del enlace y éste se subraya, también se subraya el espacio en blanco que existe entre el icono y el texto y se ve mal. ¿Cómo puedo evitar ese efecto?

Éste es el código:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>

<div id="login">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He quitado el espacio del `> Login` y le he dado al icono un `padding-right: 5px;`

```css
.glyphicon-lock {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
<div id="login">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>Login
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: oh que simple y que genio hahah

Answer (score 2):

Yo suelo separar los elementos internos de los enlaces o botones con `span`, así puedo controlar cada elemento de forma independiente.

```css
.Boton:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Boton:hover .Boton__text {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>

<div id="login">
  <a class="Boton" href="#">
    <i class="Boton__icon glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="Boton__text">Login</span>
  </a>
</div>
```